# Don't want Unity animation to return object to original position

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to animate a playing card's position and rotation.  I set an initial and final position/rotation.  Nothing fancy, just move from point A to point B and spin it.  I created a trigger to start the animation in code - _animator.SetTrigger("MyTrigger").  The animation works fine except that it returns the object to its original position when complete.  How do I make it stay at its final position/rotation?

Some forums/posts say that I just need to set the Animation.WrapMode.  Some say that I need to set Animator.ApplyRootMotion.

When I set Animator.ApplyRootMotion, the animation starts at the object's current position, ignoring my initial position.  Not what I want.  I suppose I could move the object before I trigger the animation, but it doesn't seem like I should have to.

I would like to try the Animation.WrapMode method, but I do not have an Animation component or am unaware of how to get a reference to an Animation component.  When creating the animation, Unity added an Animator component to my object, but not an Animation component.  Do I need to add my own?  I tried that, but am unsure of what properties need to be set, etc.  Most of all, I am unsure of the relationship between the Animation component,  Animator component, and everything else.

How do I get the animation to leave my object at point B?  If anyone can elaborate a little about the various animation components, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: I suggest reading through the unity [manual for animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html).

Comment: Yes, I thought of that :-) The manual really doesn't address the issue.  

In addition, I have viewed many videos.  Most are much more complex than my issue and not helpful for me.  Most want to focus on importing complex animations.  The simpler videos seem to have no need to do what I want.

Comment: I mentioned the manual because your 3rd paragraph had a lot of uncertainty regarding the components.  It may also lead you to a solution indirectly, by giving you better search terms or understanding on specific concepts or workflows.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to add an animation that just sets the position of the card to the desired position, so when the movement animation ends, it transist to this new state and the card remais in the desired position